# Preventing code in one workbook affecting other workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have one workbook named "test" that I have written a code to hide the workbook and show a user-form. The problem I am facing is that when I have one or more workbooks open then I open "test" workbook, all other workbooks become hidden. This is the code I use in module1:

```
 Sub auto_open()
Application.Visible = False
Windows("test").Visible = False

UserForm2.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Comment: this is the code for saving the wb but not for closing. please edit your question with the code for closing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
Windows("test").Visible = False
```

This will hide ALL excel windows. Not only one workbook.

What I think from those you told us that you actually need is:

```
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
```

or

```
Windows("Book1.xlsm").Visible = False
```

The difference is that I make the whole **SPECIFIC** Workbook (full name) to disappear. Not only a sheet.

If you want a specific sheet though you can use:

```
Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Visible = False
```

Comment: i just tried both codes and still not working. if any workbook is opened/active, then i open the workbook that has my code, what happens is that the first workbook also becomes hidden too.

Comment: I really doubt that. I just tested it again.

Comment: Do the following:
Create workbook named Book1.xlsx
Create macro enabled workbook name Book2.xlsm
Add on Book2 -> This Workbook-> the following:
Sub test()
    Windows("Book2.xlsm").Visible = False
End Sub
Open Book1
Run macro. It should work

Comment: i dont know whats with my code then. here is the change i have made  Sub auto_open()
Application.Visible = False
Windows("test.xlsm").Visible = False
UserForm2.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Comment: Comment out the Application.Visible = False. That is your problem now. It makes the whole Excel application hidden. All open workbooks.

Comment: the issue is that the workbook is hidden in userform, you call the workbook to open by clicking a command button on the userform

Comment: i have done as you asked and it works great. thank you

Comment: one more issue, it happens that when i am on the userform then i open another workbook and close this workbook i just opened, it causes my userform to close

Comment: Yes. This is the default behavior. When you close the workbook it closes everything that goes with it. You have to find another way around that issue but this is a topic for another question. If you want create a new question for that.

Comment: @MbarackSaeed If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox near the answer to accept it and help future users on this community to find easily the answer in your question.